# JavaFX Progress Indicator not updating across threads

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, concurrency, progress-bar

I am trying to implement a progress indicator in my JavaFX Interface class, which updates accordingly to my "Reader" class which parses through a log and keeps track of the progress it has made.

My current approach is making a seperate thread which runs Reader (this is because the Interface would become unresponsive when running Reader), and as the Reader makes progress, it will update the Interfaces progress indicator directly.

Interface Class:

```
public class Interface extends Application {

public ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(0);
public ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(0);

private BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
private Stage stage = new Stage();
private Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 400, 190);
private Button run = new Button();
private Button browseInputPath = new Button();
private Button browseOutputPath = new Button();
private CheckBox runAutomatically = new CheckBox("Run Automatically");
private TextField inputPath = new TextField();
private TextField outputPath = new TextField();
private HBox InputPath = new HBox(5);
private HBox OutputPath = new HBox(5);
private HBox progress = new HBox(10);
private File configFile = new File("config.txt");
private JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {

    initializeConfigFile();
    initializeHBoxes();
    initializeProps();

    bp.setTop(progress);
    bp.setBottom(OutputPath);
    bp.setCenter(InputPath);

    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    if ( runAutomatically.isSelected() ) { runReader(); }

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void runReader() {

    run.setDisable(true);
    browseInputPath.setDisable(true);
    browseOutputPath.setDisable(true);
    inputPath.setDisable(true);
    outputPath.setDisable(true);

    Reader reader = new Reader(inputPath.getText(), outputPath.getText());
    Thread t = new Thread(reader, "thread");
    t.start();

    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> { t.stop(); });

}

private void writeConfigFile(Boolean runAuto, String inputPath, String outputPath) throws FileNotFoundException {

    PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(configFile, false));
    printer.println("RunAutomatically: " + runAuto);
    printer.println("InputDirectory: " + inputPath);
    printer.println("OutputDirectory: " + outputPath);
    printer.close();

}

private void initializeConfigFile() throws IOException {

    if ( !configFile.exists() ) {

        File inputFolder = new File("input");
        File outputFolder = new File("output");
        inputFolder.mkdir();
        outputFolder.mkdir();
        writeConfigFile(false, inputFolder.getAbsolutePath(), outputFolder.getAbsolutePath());

    } 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(configFile);

    while ( input.hasNext() ) {

        if ( input.next().contains("RunAutomatically:") ) {

            String temp = input.next();

            if ( temp.contains("true")) { 

                runAutomatically.setSelected(true);

            } else { runAutomatically.setSelected(false); }
        }

        if ( input.next().contains("InputDirectory:") ) { inputPath.setText(input.next()); }

        if ( input.next().contains("OutputDirectory:") ) { outputPath.setText(input.next()); }

    }

    input.close();
}

private void initializeHBoxes() {

    InputPath.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 10, 12 ));
    InputPath.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");
    InputPath.getChildren().add(inputPath);
    InputPath.getChildren().add(browseInputPath);

    OutputPath.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12 ));
    OutputPath.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");
    OutputPath.getChildren().add(outputPath);
    OutputPath.getChildren().add(browseOutputPath);

    progress.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12 ));
    progress.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");
    progress.getChildren().add(run);
    progress.getChildren().add(runAutomatically);

    progress.getChildren().add(pb);
    progress.getChildren().add(pi);

}

private void initializeProps() {

    run.setText("Start");
    run.setPrefSize(75, 40);
    Tooltip runHelper = new Tooltip("Begins process to parse log files. Files are taken from input directory path and completed files are placed in output directory path.");
    Tooltip.install(run, runHelper);
    run.setOnAction(event -> { runReader(); });

    pb.setPrefSize(125, 30);
    Tooltip pbHelper = new Tooltip("Total Transactions Completed for File");
    Tooltip.install(pb, pbHelper);

    pi.setPrefSize(100, 100);
    Tooltip piHelper = new Tooltip("Total Files Completed");
    Tooltip.install(pi, piHelper);

    browseInputPath.setText(" ... ");
    browseInputPath.setPrefSize(75, 30);
    browseInputPath.setOnAction(event -> {

        fc.setDialogTitle("Choose Input Directory");
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int returnValue = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

        if ( returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { inputPath.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); }

    });

    browseOutputPath.setText(" ... ");
    browseOutputPath.setPrefSize(75, 30);
    browseOutputPath.setOnAction(event -> {

        fc.setDialogTitle("Choose Output Directory");
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int returnValue = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

        if ( returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { outputPath.setText(fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); }

    });

    runAutomatically.setOnAction(e -> { 

        try {

            if ( runAutomatically.isSelected() ) {

                writeConfigFile(true, inputPath.getText(), outputPath.getText()); 

            } else { writeConfigFile(false, inputPath.getText(), outputPath.getText()); }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2 ) { e2.printStackTrace(); }

    });

    Tooltip autoRunHelper = new Tooltip("If selected, program will automatically run on program startup.");
    Tooltip.install(runAutomatically, autoRunHelper);

    inputPath.setPrefSize(300, 30);
    Tooltip inputPathHelper = new Tooltip("Input Path Directory");
    Tooltip.install(inputPath, inputPathHelper);

    outputPath.setPrefSize(300, 30);
    Tooltip outputPathHelper = new Tooltip("Output Path Directory");
    Tooltip.install(outputPath, outputPathHelper);  
    }
}
```

Reader Class:

```
public class Reader extends Interface implements Runnable {

private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> database;
private String storeInfo;
private String date;
private String inputDirectory;
private String outputDirectory;
private int finalTransactionNumber;
private int firstTransactionNumber;
private int totalTransactions = 0;
private int completedTransactions = 0;
private int totalFiles = 0;
private int completedFiles = 0;

public Reader(String inputDirectory, String outputDirectory) {

    this.inputDirectory = inputDirectory;
    this.outputDirectory = outputDirectory;

}

public void run() {

    try {

        File[] directory = new File(inputDirectory).listFiles();
        totalFiles = directory.length;

        for ( int i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++ ) {

            completedTransactions = 0;
            initializeArrayList(directory[i]);
            storeInfo = retrieveStoreInfo(directory[i]);
            date = retrieveLogDate(directory[i]);

            new File(outputDirectory + "\\" + date).mkdirs();
            File output = new File(outputDirectory + "\\" + date + "\\" + storeInfo + ".txt");

            readFile(directory[i]);
            writeTransactionInfo(output);
            updateFileProgress();

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } 
}

/**
 * Updates progress bar from extended interface class by calculating completed transactions per file.
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
private void updateTransactionProgress() { 

    if ( totalTransactions == 0 ) { super.pb.setProgress(0); }

    completedTransactions++;
    super.pb.setProgress( (completedTransactions + 0.0) / totalTransactions );

    System.out.println(pb.getProgress());
}

/**
 * Updates progress indicator (pie chart) from extended interface class by calculating total completed files.
 */
private void updateFileProgress() {

    if ( totalFiles == 0 ) { super.pi.setProgress(0); }

    completedFiles++;
    super.pi.setProgress( (completedFiles + 0.0) / totalFiles );

}

/**
 * Scans log file to retrieve and save transaction information.
 * Time Complexity: O(n)
 * @param inputFile
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
private void readFile(File inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {

        int transactionNumber = firstTransactionNumber;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);

        while ( transactionNumber < finalTransactionNumber ) {

            String tempTime = input.next();
            String tempLine = input.nextLine();

            if ( !database.get(0).get(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber).equals("-1") && !database.get(1).get(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber).equals("-1") && !database.get(2).get(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber).equals("-1") && !database.get(3).get(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber).equals("-1")) {

                System.out.println("found transaction: " + transactionNumber);
                updateTransactionProgress();
                transactionNumber++;

            } else if ( tempLine.contains("StartTransaction") && tempLine.contains("#" + transactionNumber) ) {

                database.get(0).set(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber, tempTime);

            } else if ( tempLine.contains("EndTransaction") && tempLine.contains("#" + transactionNumber) ) {

                database.get(1).set(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber, tempTime);

            } else if ( tempLine.contains("FTransType=") && tempLine.contains("" + transactionNumber) ) {

                if ( database.get(2).get(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber).equals("-1") ) {

                    database.get(2).set(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber, (parseTransactionType(tempLine)));

                } else {

                    database.get(3).set(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber, (parseTransactionType(tempLine)));

                }

            } else if ( tempLine.contains("PrePayTrsNumber=") && tempLine.contains("#" + transactionNumber)) {

                database.get(4).set(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber, "Prepaid");

            } else if ( !input.hasNextLine() ) {

                if ( database.get(1).get(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber).equals("-1") && database.get(3).get(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber).equals("-1") ) {

                    database.get(1).set(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber, "");
                    database.get(3).set(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber, "");

                } else if ( database.get(3).get(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber).equals("-1") ) {

                    database.get(3).set(transactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber, "");

                }

                input.close();
                input = new Scanner(inputFile);
            }
        }

        input.close();
    }

/**
 * Creates and fills database ArrayList which holds individual ArrayLists for each type of transaction information.
 * Also instantiates variables which assist the log scanning process.
 * @param inputFile
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
private void initializeArrayList( File inputFile ) throws FileNotFoundException {

    firstTransactionNumber = retrieveFirstTransactionNumber(inputFile);
    finalTransactionNumber = retrieveFinalTransactionNumber(inputFile, firstTransactionNumber);
    totalTransactions = (finalTransactionNumber - firstTransactionNumber);

    System.out.println(firstTransactionNumber);
    System.out.println(finalTransactionNumber);

    //database[0] = startTimes; database[1] = endTimes; database[2] = FTransType1; database[3] = FTransType2; database[4] = isPrepaid
    database = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(5);

    for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { database.add(new ArrayList<String>(totalTransactions)); }

    for ( int i = 0; i < totalTransactions; i++ ) {

        database.get(0).add("-1");
        database.get(1).add("-1");
        database.get(2).add("-1");
        database.get(3).add("-1");
        database.get(4).add("");

    }
}

/**
 * Parses strings from transaction log to retrieve transaction type.
 * @param tempLine
 * @return transaction type
 */
private String parseTransactionType(String tempLine) {

    if ( tempLine.contains("Sale")) { 

        return "Sale"; 

    } else if ( tempLine.contains("Void")) {

        return "Void";

    } else if ( tempLine.contains("PayOut")) {

        return "PayOut";

    } else if ( tempLine.contains("PayIn")) {

        return "PayIn";

    } else if ( tempLine.contains("Drop")) {

        return "Drop";

    } else if ( tempLine.contains("CloseBank")) {

        return "CloseBank";

    } else if ( tempLine.contains("OpenBank")) {

        return "OpenBank";

    } else if ( tempLine.contains("Refund")) {

        return "Refund";

    } else { return ""; }
}

/**
 * Writes transaction information withheld in the database ArrayList to output file.
 * @param outputFile
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
private void writeTransactionInfo(File outputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {

    try {

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile, false));
        writer.close();

        writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true));

        for ( int i = 0; i < database.get(0).size(); i++ ) {

                writer.println(firstTransactionNumber + i + "," + database.get(0).get(i) + "," + database.get(1).get(i) + "," + database.get(2).get(i) + ","
                + database.get(3).get(i) + "," + database.get(4).get(i) + "," + storeInfo + "," + date);

        }

        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

/**
 * Used to initialize transaction number variable; Locates first transaction number used.
 * @param inputFile
 * @return transaction number
 * @return -1 if transaction number is not found
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
private int retrieveFirstTransactionNumber(File inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);

    while ( input.hasNext() ) {

        String temp = input.next();

        if ( temp.contains("StartTransaction") ) {

            temp = input.next();

            if ( temp.equals("Trs") ) {

                temp = input.next();
                input.close();
                temp = temp.substring(1, temp.length());
                return Integer.parseInt(temp);

            }
        }
    }

    input.close();
    return -1;
}

/**
 * Returns last transaction number in log; used to determine when file reader should stop.
 * @param inputFile
 * @param firstTransactionNumber
 * @return -1 if not found
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
private int retrieveFinalTransactionNumber(File inputFile, int firstTransactionNumber) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
    String temp = null;
    int finalTransactionNumber = -1;

    while ( input.hasNextLine() ) {

        temp = input.nextLine();

        if ( temp.contains("#" + Integer.toString(firstTransactionNumber).substring(0, 1)) && temp.contains("StartTransaction")) {

            finalTransactionNumber = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(87, 94));

        }
    }

    input.close();
    return finalTransactionNumber;
}

/**
 * Retrieves register ID and store number
 * @param inputFile
 * @return computerName
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
private String retrieveStoreInfo(File inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
    String computerName = null;

    while ( computerName == null && input.hasNext() ) {

        String temp = input.next();

        if ( temp.startsWith("SPR") ) { computerName = temp; }
    }

    input.close();
    return computerName;
}

/**
 * Retrieves date of log file
 * @param inputFile
 * @return date
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
private String retrieveLogDate(File inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
    String temp = null;

    while ( input.hasNext() ) {

        temp = input.next();

        if ( temp.contains("Date:")) {

            temp = input.next().replace('/', '-');
            input.close();
            return temp;

        }
    }

    input.close();
    return "";
}
```

}

When I check the progress of the progressBar after each time 'updateTransactionProgress()' is called, the value is updating properly. It just isn't updating the progressBar in the Interface class.

I am new to multithreading and not sure if I am understanding it correctly. I have looked up tutorials and other examples but haven't found much help. I would appreciate the help.

EDIT: included entire class files for more detail.

Comment: What thread is `updateTransactionProgress()` called on? If it's called on the background thread, remember: only update the UI on the JavaFX Application Thread. To run code on the FX thread from another thread, use [`Platform.runLater(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)).

Comment: IMO there isn't enough info here to answer the question, only enough information to speculate on what the issue may be and how to address that speculative issue.  Edit the question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your `Reader` class extends a different class than you're thinking. You call `super.progressBar.setProgress()`, which is calling the parent class `Interface`'s progress bar to change it. Even if `Interface` extends `GUI` class, the `progressBar` in `GUI` is private, so you can't access it. I'd suggest that you pass the progress bar from your `GUI` class to the `Reader` when you instantiate the `Reader`.

```
public class GUI extends Application {

    private ProgressBar _progressBar = new ProgressBar(0);

    // Methods which display GUI w/ progressBar

    private void runReader() {
      // progressBar should be instantiated by now, of course
      Reader reader = new Reader(_progressBar, "input Path", "output Path");
      Thread t = new Thread(reader, "reader thread");
      t.start();
    }
}

public class Reader extends Interface implements Runnable {
     private final ProgressBar _progressBar = bar;

     public void Reader(ProgressBar bar, String in, String out){
         _progressBar = bar;
         // Rest of constructor here
     }
    //Main processing methods that call 'updateTransactionProgress()'

    private void updateTransactionProgress() {

        if ( totalTransactions == 0 ) { super.pb.setProgress(0); }
        completedTransactions++;.

        // Call to Platform.runLater() to run the update on the JavaFX Application Thread
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            _progressBar.setProgress((completedTransactions + 0.0) / 
            totalTransactions);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: An underscore to start a variable?

Comment: This works, Thank you! Though, I don't understand how updating the ProgressBar variable local to the Reader class updates the ProgressBar in the Interface class.

Answer (score -2):

Without enough information to make an informed guess, I suggest you add a `Thread.sleep()` to your `Reader` thread's `run()` implementation. From what you've posted it's likely your Reader thread is consuming all available processor time without resting, so the GUI thread never has a chance to jump in and update the display.

If adding `Thread.sleep()` resolves the issue you posted, you'll want to determine an appropriate place and duration for your `Reader` thread to periodically give way in your `run()` implementation.

Comment: Maybe downvoters could comment on why the downvote. I don't see any other answers to this question.

Comment: This does not answer the question. In fairness, the question as posted isn't really answerable anyway.